# How to be informed of mouse/keyboard events in a non-focus application?

Tags: qt, visual-c++, event-handling

I must implement a master application that starts other applications. If the user does not interact with the computer during a given time, the master application is supposed to kill the current slave application (only one can be started at a time).

So, for this I need to detect user actions (keyboard, mouse) knowing that the master application has no more the focus. But I do not know how to do this. I'm under Visual C++ 2017. And I'm using Qt 5.9.1 for the GUI.

On Windows documentation I have seen some posts about "hook" functions. But I do not know if (and how) I can use it for this particular purpose.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK,
Finally I found the solution. Hook functions correspond to me needs. I found the perfect example for my problem: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CppWindowsHook-06957865

Comment: As usual Windows document is really poor. Hooking WH_MOUSE I has some troubles (mouse click did not work). But hooking WH_MOUSE_LL works well.